# How do I change default Docker Repository for use in Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I am new to Docker. I work in a closed environment (e.g., no access to the internet) I have a simple Dockerfile as follows:

```
FROM alpine 
LABEL maintainer="dwa"
RUN apk add --update nodejs modejs-npm
COPY SimpleServer.js /src
WORKDIR /src
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 8083
ENTRYPOINT["node", "./SimpleServer.js"]
```

When I try to run the image build like this:

**docker image build -t web:latest .**

I receive the following error

```
get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:53: read udp xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx..... i/o tmeout
(alpine, etc...)
```

I have access  to all the images in a separate repository which I can access via the internal web.
Question: Is it possible to configure Docker to look at my specific repository before it looks for the 'official' repo and if so how do I do that?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can point repository in dockerfile:

```
FROM your_repository/your_image:your_version
```

Example:

```
FROM myrepo/alpine
LABEL maintainer="dwa"
RUN apk add --update nodejs modejs-npm
COPY SimpleServer.js /src
WORKDIR /src
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 8083
ENTRYPOINT["node", "./SimpleServer.js"]
```

Comment: Thanks...can myrepo contain a fully qualified URL or does it need to be a local file? e.g., https://some-server/somelocation

Comment: it should be fully qualified url

Comment: here you can find some additional data on private docker registry (might be useful for you): https://docs.docker.com/registry/

Comment: Very useful, indeed! I appreciate you taking the time to help. That documentation had the answer I neded...the daemon.json file was what I needed to configure.

Answer (score 0):

just add something like this to your FROM comamnd

```
FROM your_specific_docker_registy_name/name_of_image:tag_of_you_want
```